# In Young's double slit experiment the fringes are non-localised. Why?

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment

What is meaning of non localiesd fringe ?Why they are non localised ?

Comment: Pllease show a bit more effort when asking questions. Include the relevant information (that this is about the double slit experiment, for instance) into the question itself, not only in the title. Give a bit of background - where have you heard of "non-localized fringes", and where are they supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

It means that fringes can be seen everywhere to the right of the double slit arrangement if the source is to the left of the double slit.  They occur because coherent waves for the two slits actually overlap and hence form an interference pattern to the right of the double slits.

For some arrangement used to show interference the coherent waves from different sources are divergent and hence those will never overlap to produce interference fringes unless forced to by a lens.  To do this the lens has to be focussed on the region where the divergent waves appear to come from.  That is where the fringes are localised.